# How to handle database connectivity exceptions in one place

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, entity-framework-5, repository-pattern

I'm using WPF, Entity Framework 5, and am trying to implement some kind of Repository pattern and handle connection exceptions in an elegant manner.

I understand the concept of wrapping a database CRUD operation in a Try/Catch block, to handle the case where the database cannot be connected to. Of course there are multiple exceptions that can be thrown for each operation, such as a foreign key constraint violation. Ok... so I create an elaborate Try/Catch block to handle all the exceptions comprehensively... but that's just ONE operation! Obviously a real-world application is going to have code for dozens or hundreds of CRUD operations. Surely it cannot be best practice to duplicate the elaborate try/catch block for every individual CRUD operation. 
Is this sort of thing best handled at the application level, where individual CRUDs don't bother with catching exceptions, which then bubble up to the top where unhandled exceptions are caught?
Ideally I'd like my app to have an overall database connection status, which will be set to "disconnected" if any CRUD operation fails due to a connection-related issue.

How do professional apps handle this? What basic thing am I missing??

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to create a Data Access Layer, where all of your database functions are routed through one class. In this way, you can handle all of the `Exception`s in one place. In my applications, I extend this idea a bit by handling standard (expected) `Exception`s in one place and then packaging the database query results into a helper class that can contain the `Exception` if one occurred as well as the results. Not wanting to give all of my code away, here is a simplified example:

```
public GetDataOperationResult<TResult> TryGet<TResult>(Func<TResult> function, int maximumRetryCount, string successText, string undeterminedErrorText)
{
    Debug.Assert(function != null, "The function input parameter of the DataOperationManager.TryGet<TResult>() method must not be null.");
    for (int index = 0; index < maximumRetryCount; index++)
    {
        try
        {
            TResult result = function();
            return new GetDataOperationResult<TResult>(result, successText, undeterminedErrorText);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            if (index == maximumRetryCount - 1) return new GetDataOperationResult<TResult>(exception, successText, undeterminedErrorText);
            int sleepCount = GetSleepTime(index, minimumDelay);
            Thread.Sleep(sleepCount);
        }
    } 
    return new GetDataOperationResult<TResult>(default(TResult), successText, undeterminedErrorText);
}
```

The database call gets passed in as a `Func<TResult>` (same as `Func<T>`) and this method is called like this:

```
public GetDataOperationResult<User> GetUser(Guid userId)
{
    return DataManager.TryGet<User>(() => DataProvider.GetUser(userId), "The user was 
loaded successfully", "There was a problem loading the user");
}
```

While I don't care to show the `GetDataOperationResult` class, this is where the standard `Exception` handling goes, along with user feedback message generation and/or manipulation. I'm sure that you can handle your own `Exception`s without this. One final point to make is that I also have `TrySet` and asynchronous get/set methods in my class... it's *not* all handled by one method.

Comment: I see... so inside `GetDataOperationResult` is where you would differentiate between, say `EntityException` and `EntityNotFoundException` or some generic `Exception`? If so, do you use the `Entity Exception` to flag the database as being disconnected to the rest of the application?

Comment: I'm not using the `Entity Framework` in this application, but yes, the `GetDataOperationResult` class (or actually an abstract base class) is where I handle expected `Exceptions` and package up unexpected `Exception`s into a property of the class to be handled back in the UI... it's just done in the constructor.

Comment: So does that mean that each and every database call from the UI also has to interrogate the exception property and deal with it?

Comment: When I say handled, I really should have said displayed. By that I mean that after taking out the result, I pass the `GetDataOperationResult` object to my user feedback system so that the error messages you can see in the example can be displayed to the user. To clarify my earlier statement, if an `Exception` occurs, it'll go into the `GetDataOperationResult` object whether it's used in the UI or not. All `Exception`s are dealt with in the `GetDataOperationResult` class but if the `Exception` is 'expected' a predetermined message is displayed and if not, the message in my example is displayed.